# convert formula in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Hi I need that formula to be converted into a usuable format in excel:
t will equal a list of number in a column, so for instance use t = 1

thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Write it out as you would do it on a simple calculator then think of the functions you need in excel. If I put it into my HP48SX it can be sokved exactly as you have it stated in your question.

Comment: when I try to do the ^ it doesnt work, and I don't know how to make all the functions, I asked for a converted format

Answer (score 1):

I took a shot at it where A1 is the cell that holds t

```
=((A1/693)^5.526)*10^(((0.9998^A1)*2*(ABS(SIN(2.983*A1^(1/4)-0.57))*-1)^2)-1)
```

Comment: Notice the solution above. When you have formulas like this to work up in Excel, start as close to the innermost factors and start adding parentheses. Work in stages and check it along the way. For example, start with `=2.983*A1^(1/4)-0.57` and check the result. Then, put parentheses around it and build the next part and check again: `ABS(SIN(2.983*A1^(1/4)-0.57))*-1)^2`. When you build it in stages, you can be sure that each part works. Nothing more difficult than looking at a complicated formula that doesn't work, and not knowing where to start.

Comment: the formula isn't working properly and it's not mine, so I can't check the intermediate calculation to see if it's correct, I know how it should behave as I saw a graphic of this formula and that's not the right one, why 1/4? it's a square root

Comment: nothing more difficult than asking for some help and getting answers that don't even make any progress into resolving the issue...

Comment: @elcamino its not a square root.. its a 4th root which is the same as x^(1/4)

Comment: 4th root ? never heard of it, how would you describe it? the thing is, when I saw the graph of this formula, it's making "mountains" shapes, but with the formula, It's not

Comment: @elcamino - the square root is x^(1/2).  The fourth root is x^(1/4).  The fourth root of 10000 is 10.  Similarly, the square root of 100 is 10.